# Add date by one

Tags: java, date

hii all
I have date in string form
I want to convert it into first date form and increase date to one like

`12-12-2000`

to

`13-12-2000`

and want to re convert that increased date to string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
String date = "2011-05-01"; 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(df.parse(date));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // how many days you want to add like here 1
String addeddate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. DateFormat for parsing and formatting. [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.text/DateFormatparseStringdateString.htm)
2. [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).roll(...) for date arithmetic. [Example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-perform-datetime-arithmetic-with-javas-calendar-class/116)

**NOTE**: Do not forget **setLenient(true)**. [Example](http://www.codingdiary.com/developers/developers/diary/javaapi/java/text/SampleCode/DateFormatSetLenientExampleCode.html)

Comment: Why is `setLenient(true)` so important in this case?

Comment: @Jesper this is important when you are rolling dates