# How do I add one month to current date in Java?

Tags: java, java-time

In Java how can I add one month to the current date?

Comment: related [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Answer (score 137):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: thanx piyush , and what this cal date format, i need to store this in mysql

Comment: mysql data type for date is DATETIME.

Comment: is this correct date format that cal return , that i can use to store in mysql

Comment: The question was different than what you are asking now. However, in MySQL you can use DATE_ADD function to perform the date arithmetics. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: The Java code to add a month to current date in the desired format would be as shown below. Now, it's upto you to convert this String to a date and insert in into MYSql database. Note, that you can change the date format in DateFormat constructor or later in the MYSQL query using STR_TO_DATE(str, format) function.                                                                 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
String dateString = formatter.format(now.getTime());

Comment: cant i manipulate the date fro jave to convert it into mysql format ?

Comment: Sure. I have included the code above in order to accomplish that using the Date Format object in Java.

Comment: This is outdated now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905416/adding-one-month-to-current-date/29250229#29250229

Comment: public String addDays() {
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        date = cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String strDate = formatter.format(date);
        return strDate;
    }

Answer (score 64):

**Java 8**

```
LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1);
```

Comment: To have java.util.Date:

Date.from((LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1)).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())

Comment: It requires a minimum API level of 26. so top answer is better

Answer (score 39):

You can make use of apache's commons lang DateUtils helper utility class.

```
Date newDate = DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(), 1);
```

You can download commons lang jar at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Answer (score 34):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate::plusMonths
```

Example:

```
LocalDate.now( )
         .plusMonths( 1 );
```

Better to specify time zone.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
         .plusMonths( 1 );
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### Date-only

If you want the date-only, use the `LocalDate` class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
 LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

> today.toString(): 2017-01-23

Add a month.

```
LocalDate oneMonthLater = today.plusMonths( 1 );
```

> oneMonthLater.toString(): 2017-02-23

### Date-time

Perhaps you want a time-of-day along with the date.

First get the current moment in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Adding a month means determining dates. And determining dates means applying a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the world with a new day dawning earlier to the east. So adjust that `Instant` into a time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Now add your month. Let java.time handle Leap month, and the fact that months vary in length.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMonthLater = zdt.plusMonths( 1 );
```

You might want to adjust the time-of-day to the first moment of the day when making this kind of calculation. That first moment is not always `00:00:00.0` so let java.time determine the time-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtMonthLaterStartOfDay = zdtMonthLater.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

Update: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its team advises migration to the java.time classes. I am leaving this section intact for posterity.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library offers a method to add months in a smart way.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
DateTime nextMonth = now.plusMonths( 1 );
```

You might want to focus on the day by adjust the time-of-day to the first moment of the day.

```
DateTime nextMonth = now.plusMonths( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
java.util.Date dt = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 8):

(adapted from Duggu)

```
public static Date addOneMonth(Date date)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use DateUtils class in org.apache.commons.lang3.time package

```
DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(),1);
```

Comment: Simple and easy solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use calander and try this code.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date nextMonthFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date nextMonthLastDay = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public Date  addMonths(String dateAsString, int nbMonths) throws ParseException {
        String format = "MM/dd/yyyy" ;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format) ;
        Date dateAsObj = sdf.parse(dateAsString) ;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dateAsObj);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, nbMonths);
        Date dateAsObjAfterAMonth = cal.getTime() ;
    System.out.println(sdf.format(dateAsObjAfterAMonth));
    return dateAsObjAfterAMonth ;
}`
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation as to what your code does rather than just a large code block?

Comment: My code is more restrictive and more generic. More restritive because it handles only date (in the form of string) with the  fixed format  "MM/dd/yyyy" . Generic because, it enables you to add any among of positive month on your specified date.

Comment: So, if you have to have a less restrictive code that take any java.util.Date and render another java.util.Date after adding a month, see below :  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(date); cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1); cal.getTime();

Answer (score 3):

If you need a one-liner (i.e. for Jasper Reports formula) and don't mind if the adjustment is not exactly one month (i.e "30 days" is enough):

`new Date($F{invoicedate}.getTime() + 30L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L)`

Comment: Don't forget to add 'L' suffix to number else if will be treated as simple int and will overflow to a negative number!

Comment: public static final long ONE_MONTH = 2592000000L;

Answer (score 2):

This method returns the current date plus 1 month.

```
public Date  addOneMonth()  {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        return cal.getTime();
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public Date addMonth(Date inputDate, int monthToAddNumber){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(inputDate);
        // Add 'monthToAddNumber' months to inputDate
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, monthToAddNumber);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

then call method:

```
addMonth(new Date(), 1)
```

Comment: This will not work with leap years: ie adding one month on Feb 29, will return March 29 instead of the proper value.

Answer (score 2):

Use the plusMonths() method of the LocalDate class for Java 8 and Higher Versions.

// Add one month to the current local date

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1);
```

// Add one month to any local date object

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2022-02-14").plusMonths(1); // 2022-03-14
```

Reference: https://www.javaexercise.com/java/java-add-months-to-date

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the day after one month, it is necessary to look at what day of the month it is today.

So if the day is first day of month run following code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar calFebruary = Calendar.getInstance();
    calFebruary.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);

    if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1) {// if first day of month
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Date nextMonthFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(nextMonthFirstDay);

    }
```

if the day is last day of month, run following codes.

```
    else if ((calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) {// if last day of month
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Date nextMonthLastDay = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(nextMonthLastDay);
    }
```

if the day is in february run following code

```
    else if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY
            && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > calFebruary.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {// control of february

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Date nextMonthLastDay = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(nextMonthLastDay);

    }
```

the following codes are used for other cases.

```
    else { // any day
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Date theNextDate = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(theNextDate);
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this;

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String d = "2000-01-30";
Date date= new Date(sdf.parse(d).getTime());
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

Comment: * @deprecated As of JDK version 1.1,
     * replaced by <code>Calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, int month)</code>.

As the Date.java says.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Date dateAfterOneMonth = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()).plusMonths(1).toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Constants are in Portuguese because *yes*, but javadoc is understandable enough.

Just call

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
DateSumUtil.sumOneMonth(cal);
```

and that's that. Related code:

```
package you.project.your_package_utils;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class DateSumUtil {

    private static Integer[] meses31 = { 2, 4, 7, 9 };
    private static List<Integer> meses31List = Arrays.asList(meses31);
    private static SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private static final int MES = Calendar.MONTH;
    private static final int ANO = Calendar.YEAR;
    private static final int DIA = Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;

    /**
     * Receives a date and adds one month. <br />
     * 
     * @param c date to receive an added month, as {@code java.util.Calendar}
     * @param dia day of month of the original month
     */
    public static void addOneMonth(Calendar c, int dia) throws ParseException {
    if (cal.get(MES) == 0) {            if (dia < 29)           cal.add(MES, 1);
        else {  if (cal.get(ANO) % 4 == 0) {    if (dia < 30)   cal.add(MES, 1);
                                                else            cal.setTime(s.parse("29/02/" + cal.get(ANO)));
                } else {                        if (dia < 29)   cal.add(MES, 1);
                                                else            cal.setTime(s.parse("28/02/" + cal.get(ANO)));
    }   }   } else if (meses31List.contains(cal.get(MES))) {
        if (dia < 31) {                                         cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                                                                cal.set(DIA, dia);
        } else  cal.setTime(s.parse("30/" + (cal.get(MES) + 2) + "/" + cal.get(ANO)));
    } else {                                                    cal.add(MES, 1);
                                                                cal.set(DIA, dia);  }   
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public class StringSplit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        date(5, 3);
        date(5, 4);
    }

    public static String date(int month, int week) {
        LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(month).plusWeeks(week);
        String Fudate = futureDate.toString();
        String[] arr = Fudate.split("-", 3);
        String a1 = arr[0];
        String a2 = arr[1];
        String a3 = arr[2];
        String date = a3 + "/" + a2 + "/" + a1;
        System.out.println(date);
        return date;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10/03/2020
17/03/2020
```

Comment: First of all the answer is wrong based on the OP. Second The OP was answered 8(!) years ago and third there are better ways to formatting a date output than using loads of strings.