# Add some month to current date using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

i want to add one month in current date with this format `"YYYY-MM-DD"` i want function which return date type thanks 
Example

```
2020-04-13 will be 2020-05-13
```

if there is no way please how can i use STR_TO_DATE here

```
String requeteInsert = "INSERT INTO `jardin`.`abonnement` (`id`,`enf_id`,  `data_debut`, `date_fin`,  `type`,`description`, `statu`, `statu_paiment`) VALUES ( '" + A.getId()+  "','" + A.getEnf_id()+  " ','"  + A.getData_debut()+  "','" + A.getDate_fin()+  "','" + A.getType()+  "','" + A.getDescription()+"','" + A.getStatu()+"','" + A.getStatu_paiment()+"');";
```

i'm already use LocalDate and other most of them return String after add a month .

thanks so much

Comment: Use PreparedStatements. Do not concatenate strings.

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: Where do you want to compute hte month add? At the SQL level or in Java?

Comment: You can read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: i want to add  month in java level

Comment: MySQL level: use the DATE_ADD function

Comment: Under the linked original question I in particular recommend [the answer by softarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29250229/5772882) and [the one by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25074110/5772882).

Comment: i try them all no one of them what i want most of them return not a format that i want if i use Format it's make it string and for me i want return Date

Comment: Ah, you want a `Date` with a certain format. You can’t. I added a link to an original answering that part. Also the `Date` classes are poorly designed and long outdated, you shouldn’t want to use them.

Comment: BTW `yourLocalDate.plusMonths(1)` returns a `LocalDate`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: you should use prepared statements instead of concatenating variables in the query string, which is error-prone, unsafe and inefficient.

When it comes to doing date computation: you can do the arithmetics directly in the database. This is somewhat simpler than performing it in your application code.

In MySQL, if you want the current date plus 1 month, just do: `current_date + interval 1 month`.

Here is an example of your statement, assuming that you want the new date in column `date_fin`:

```
INSERT INTO `jardin`.`abonnement` (
    `id`,
    `enf_id`,
    `data_debut`,
    `date_fin`,
    `type`,
    `description`, 
    `statu`, 
    `statu_paiment`
) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    current_date + interval 1 month,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
)
```

Alternatively, if you want to add one month to a date given as parameter:

```
INSERT INTO `jardin`.`abonnement` (
    `id`,
    `enf_id`,
    `data_debut`,
    `date_fin`,
    `type`,
    `description`, 
    `statu`, 
    `statu_paiment`
) VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ? + interval 1 month,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
)
```

PS: date parameters should be given in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, with an optional time part (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`).

Comment: thank you for your answer  it's help but some times i need to add  3 months or 6 month it's depend of the choice

Comment: @AyoubichEscobar:  `+ interval 3 month`, `+ interval 6 month`, ...

Comment: yeah hat's  last solution i will do it 3 time thanks a lot