# Modifying an objects attribute

Tags: java, oop, class, methods, attributes

I'm currently making a program that needs me to make a method that will add + 1 to the day of an existing objects date attribute. The problem is I'm not entirely sure how I modify it's value, I've tried day = day + 1, this.day + 1, etc.

So let's assume that an object date1 was equal to 1/1/1970 and I ran date1.tomorrow(); it would modify it and make it 2/1/1970.

EDIT: I'm not using java.util.Date, I made a constructor called Date with 3 fields in it.

Comment: Are you looking for `this.day++`?

Comment: I am guessing you're using a date object, so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129672/increment-existing-date-by-1-day) might help you.

Comment: Are you talking about objects of `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly modify a `Date` object by adding the integer 1 to it. This is because they are of different types. I suggest using the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object; it has a method called [`Calendar#add(int field, int amount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). That will do what you're trying to do.

**EDIT:** I had more detailed instructions, but since this question sounds like homework, I'm just leaving you with the hint above. At any rate, it should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like homework, so I don't think this should be applied.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Good point. I didn't think of that before. Usually I can spot "homeworky" questions. I will ask OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(yourDate); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
yourDate = c.getTime();
```

**EDIT**

> So let's assume that an object date1 was equal to 1/1/1970 and I ran
>   date1.tomorrow(); it would modify it and make it 2/1/1970.

If your date object (say `dt`), is an java.util.Date, you cannot do `dt.tomorrow()` unless you extend `util.Date` you could create a util class/method. e.g.:

```
class Foo {
....

public static Date tomorrow(java.util.Date yourDate){
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(yourDate); 
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

then call it:

```
dt = Foo.tomorrow(dt);
```

Comment: Would I be adding this code into my tomorrow method?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with objects of `java.util.Date` using the `+` operator on those objects isn't valid.

More importantly, even if the `+` operator had been legal, it wouldn't make any sense using it - `date + 1` should add `1` to the date or month or year..?

To manipulate an object of `java.util.Date` the class `Calendar` provides several utility methods. One of those which you can use here is [`Calendar.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29).

> Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar
>   field, based on the calendar's rules. For example, to subtract 5 days
>   from the current time of the calendar, you can achieve it by calling:

```
add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5)
```

**Edit:**

It appears from your edit that you aren't using `java.util.Date` objects. Now that your `Date` object maintains three properties (most likely date, month and year), you should be able to apply arithmetic operators on those fields.

However you should be careful to follow date related rules while manipulating those fields (assuming they belong to one of the integral types).

For example adding `1` day to `28/02/2013` should update both date and month of the `Date` instance.