# How can i increment my date by 1

Tags: java

I want to increment the date by one. I have the below code while running the code I am getting unparseable date finally I want the date as string in the format of MM-DD-YYYY.
But same program is working with the YYYY-MM-DD format but i want mydate in this format(MM-DD-YYYY)

```
String dt = schReq.getStartDate();  // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);  // number of days to add
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime()); 
schReq.setStartDate(dt);
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what is the value of `dt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding days to a date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087419/adding-days-to-a-date-in-java)

Comment: There are many other similar questions in SO. This one should be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment existing date by 1 day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129672/increment-existing-date-by-1-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be working fine as long as `dt` and `days` are correct. This gave me 12-18-2014:

```
String dt = "12-17-2014"; // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // number of days to add
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Just check the value of dt. I'm sure that is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two different DateFormats:

one for parsing the string and one for formatting.

```
String dt = schReq.getStartDate();  // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf_parser.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, days);  // number of days to add
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime()); 
schReq.setStartDate(dt);
```

Comment: Thank you Jens for your reply.if i executed the above code in the place of dt i given dt="12-17-2014" i am getting 07-07-0017 as output but i need to get 12-18-2014

Comment: @user3669480 Sorry my fauld. I have updated my answer. Please try again

Comment: again same problem now it is showing 11-05-0018 as a date

Comment: In your question you say the dt has the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and now you give the format `MM-dd-yyyy`. Here is something worng.