# generate dates between two date in Android

Tags: android, datetime, date, android-date

How to get all dates between two dates in Android.

For example. I have two Strings.

```
String first="2012-07-15";  
String second="2012-07-21";
```

I convert and get dates from these strings.

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");                                    
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
String mydate = df2.format(df1.parse(first));
```

This way I get both dates from first and second String.

Now I also display all dates between these two dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java) - You can run the increment in a loop to create the date series.

Comment: Perhaps not yet available in Android, but in regular Java use [`LocalDate::datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate)): `LocalDate.parse( "2012-07-15" ).datesUntil( "2012-07-21" )` yields a [`Stream<LocalDate>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

it is better not to use any hardcoded values in date calculations. we can rely on java `Calendar` class methods to do this task

see the code

```
private static List<Date> getDates(String dateString1, String dateString2)
{
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;

    try {
        date1 = df1 .parse(dateString1);
        date2 = df1 .parse(dateString2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);


    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    while(!cal1.after(cal2))
    {
        dates.add(cal1.getTime());
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

and use it as below

```
    List<Date> dates = getDates("2012-02-01", "2012-03-01");
    for(Date date:dates)
        System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: `DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` this line says incompatable types for me. when I change it to `SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");` then it works for me

Comment: @AkhilaMadari You have to use classes `java.text.DateFormat` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. Please check if you have imported classes from correct packages.

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DummyWorks extends Activity 
{
static final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getDatesBetween("03/23/2011","03/28/2011");
}

public static void getDatesBetween(String startDate,String endDate) {


    long  from=Date.parse(startDate);  

    long to=Date.parse(endDate);  

    int x=0;

    while(from <= to) {
          x=x+1;
          System.out.println ("Dates  : "+new Date(from));
          from += ONE_DAY;
    }
    System.out.println ("No of Dates  :"+ x);


 }
}
```

Comment: Adding milliseconds to your date brings a high risk of failure due to daylight savings and other weird timezone changes.

Comment: thanks @assylias, now i tested it.its getting correct result after changing "long ONE_DAY"

Comment: hello @Ramkiran thanks for reply. But i got error at `long from = Date.parse(startDate);` which says that java.illegalArgumentException at java.util.Date.parse.

Comment: My date format is 2012-07-15. i need to format it with your date format? what i add to this function?

Comment: Yes i think thats why i get error. What is change in getDatesBetween() function?

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Kotlin:
It will return List of Date between 2 dates.

```
 fun getDatesBetween(dateString1:String, dateString2:String):List<String> {
        val dates = ArrayList<String>()
        val input = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
        var date1:Date? = null
        var date2:Date? = null
        try
        {
            date1 = input.parse(dateString1)
            date2 = input.parse(dateString2)
        }
        catch (e:ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val cal1 = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal1.time = date1
        val cal2 = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal2.time = date2
        while (!cal1.after(cal2))
        {
            val output = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
            dates.add(output.format(cal1.time))
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        return dates
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. `LocalDate` is the class to use for a date (without time of day). I was assuming you wanted all the dates inclusive of the two given ones.

```
    String first = "2012-07-15";
    String second = "2012-07-21";
    
    List<LocalDate> dates = LocalDate.parse(first)
            .datesUntil(LocalDate.parse(second).plusDays(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(dates);
```

Output:

> [2012-07-15, 2012-07-16, 2012-07-17, 2012-07-18, 2012-07-19,
> 2012-07-20, 2012-07-21]

`LocalDate.datesUntil()` gives us a stream of dates *exclusive* of the specified end date, so we need to add one day to it to have it included.

I am exploiting the fact that your strings are in ISO 8601 format and that `LocalDate` parses this format as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

### Or through ThreeTenABP

If for some reason you are using the ThreeTenABP library rather than desugaring, I believe that the `datesUntil` method is not there. In this case use a loop instead.

```
    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.parse(first);
    LocalDate lastDate = LocalDate.parse(second);
    while (! currentDate.isAfter(lastDate )) {
        dates.add(currentDate);
        currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
    }
```

> [2012-07-15, 2012-07-16, 2012-07-17, 2012-07-18, 2012-07-19,
> 2012-07-20, 2012-07-21]

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

```
        val currentDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val mCurrentDate = getDateChanger(currentDateCalendar.time, "yyyy-MM-dd")
        currentDateCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
        val oneMonthNextCalendar = currentDateCalendar
        val mNextDate = getDateChanger(oneMonthNextCalendar.time, "yyyy-MM-dd")

        val mDates = datesBetween(
            mCurrentDate,
            mNextDate,
            "yyyy-MM-dd"
        )
        for (date in mDates)
            Log.i("DatesBetween",date)





 @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    fun getDateChanger(mDate:Date,formatter: String): String {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(formatter)
        return dateFormat.format(mDate)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    fun datesBetween(startDate: String, endDate: String,formatter: String): List<String> {
        val dates = ArrayList<String>()
        val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(formatter)
        var sDate: Date? = null
        var eDate: Date? = null
        try {
            sDate = dateFormat.parse(startDate)
            eDate = dateFormat.parse(endDate)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val sCalendarDate = Calendar.getInstance()
        sCalendarDate.time = sDate!!
        val eCalendarDate = Calendar.getInstance()
        eCalendarDate.time = eDate!!
        while (!sCalendarDate.after(eCalendarDate)) {
            dates.add(dateFormat.format(sCalendarDate.time))
            sCalendarDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        return dates
    }
```