# How do I get selected dates from CalendarView and store them in Parse.com

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I use Parse.com as backend, and I want work with calendarview in order to let the users select a range of dates and store them in parse. Then I will retrieve that information to set it in a differen CalendarView. I am using CalendarListView explained [here](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview)

Now in the sample they provide I see this method:

```
@Override
public void onDateRangeSelected(SimpleMonthAdapter.SelectedDays<SimpleMonthAdapter.CalendarDay> selectedDays)
{

    Log.e("Date range selected", selectedDays.getFirst().toString() + " --> " + selectedDays.getLast().toString());
}
```

So if I want to store that in parse, should I use an Array, how do I store secteddays in parse.
There is another library that I was trying to use, [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3844) which is similar to the previous and its method to get selected days is:

```
@Override
    public void alertSelectedFail(FailEven even) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "alertSelectedFail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

So As you can see I can get a List of dates from this method, so how do I storage that in Parse? Should I convert that in Array? if yes How do I do it?

And once I do it I want to retrieve that and set it in a different Calendarview just to show. Plaese I am new at android, hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

The `selectedDays` returns `SelectedDays<CalendarDay>` That contains only the first and last `CalendarDay`

Seems the solutions is to manually get all days in between. See [genarate dates between two date in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412713/genarate-dates-between-two-date-in-android) answer to get a `List<Date>`

Then if you want to make an array out of that you can use the following:

```
dates[] array = new Date[list.size()];
list.toArray(array); // fill the array
```

Maybe you also need DateFormatter to correctly formate the date. Or once you have the `List<Date>` You can also just loop through the list and save them in a String array one by one by using the `toString()` method on the date.