# Java error: cannot find symbol method add(Date,int)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
I have this code:
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

    public class BillionSeconds {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Date thedate ;


            String Birthday = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your birthday in the form dd-MM-yy");

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy");
            try{
            thedate = dateFormat.parse(Birthday);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to parse date stamp");
            }
            Date newdate = thedate.add(thedate, 1);
        }
    }
```

But I get this error and I cant figure out why:

```
error: cannot find symbol method add(Date,int)
```

Comment: Where in the [Date API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is there an `add(...)` method? This question could have been answered by you with a 2 second scan of the API.

Comment: WHy have you tagged this question with "exception" when it's a compile-time error?

Comment: And if it did have an add method what would `add(thedate, 1)` add to? Add one to the year, month, day? I suggest to google "java date add". One of the hits is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Answer (score 0):

As it says, there is no `add` method in java.util.Date.
You might want to take a look at [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html). It has intelligent methods like you need. Or even better, use the third-party library [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

`add(thedate, 1);`

There is an add() **method** in `Calendar Class` **not** `Date class`....

**Eg:**

`Calendar desiredDate = toDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 4);`

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that's because [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) doesn't have an `add` method. What made you think it did?

It sounds like you *might* be thinking of the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, although then you'd want:

```
Calendar nextDay = currentDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

... which isn't quite the same thing.

I would *strongly* recommend that you abandon `Date` and `Calendar` entirely though, and instead start using [Joda Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), which is a much, much better date/time API.

Note that you should *also* get a compile-time error stating that `thedate` may not have been initialized, due to your "catch and continue" error handling.