# Create Calendars for 3 years

Tags: java, android, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

```
public static ArrayList<Calendar> getCalendarsForThreeYears() {
        if (calendars == null) {
            calendars = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
            final Calendar moving = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int targetYear = moving.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
            moving.set(moving.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
            while (!(moving.get(Calendar.YEAR) == targetYear
                    && moving.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER && moving
                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 31)) {
                final Calendar c = (Calendar) moving.clone();
                calendars.add(c);
                moving.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
            }
        }
        return calendars;
    }
```

I want this to create `Calendar` objects for *3* years (*the one before the current, the current and the next*).

However this is an infinite loop since rolling `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` when it's on the end of the month won't roll the `Calendar.MONTH`

Which is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
moving.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

will do what you want.

See [`Calendar#add(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29):

> Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar field, based on the calendar's rules.

And [`Calendar.DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE):

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `moving.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`, since roll will add the days but will not add another month when you reach the last day in month before adding a new day.
In other words, if your month is say "June" you will get 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... 30th of june, then you would expect 1st july, but you will start over at 1st june.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple use the `add()` method of the Calendar. If you want to add the year then use like `calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);` or to reduce the year `calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);`.
After setting proper datetime you can convert the date into your format using the `SimpleDateFormat`.