# Implementing correct date using Calendar into Android app

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, calendar

I am having a spot of bother trying to get the date to display correctly in my application, here is the code

```
//i declare the calendar called now
private Calendar now;

//i set up the calendar with what i believe could be the problem in setting up the wrong date
now = Calendar.getInstance();
    now.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

//whatDay being a textview, is asked to display the date
whatDay.setText(DateFormat.format("E, dd MMMM", now));
```

At the moment everything works as far as displaying the date is concerned - only it is showing the wrong date which is a bit of a problem

Comment: You can use `Calendar` to add days or whatever you want but this question is awfully vague. Do you have any relevant code to show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(MONTH, SEPTEMBER);
now.set(DAY_OF_MONTH, 22);
now.set(DAY_OF_WEEK, MONDAY);
```

you can get the values for the second params however you do that in your code. Then format `now` using [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) and add it to your `TextView`

[Calendar Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

**Edit**

I don't know how you get your dates but you can have `Constants` set in your code such as MONTH, DAY, etc... that you initialize in whatever way you want when you parse your file then use those in the `set` methods of `Calendar`. There is also an `add` method of `Calendar that will add to the field values (MONTH, DAY_OF_WEEK, etc...) instead of setting them to the value in your second`param`. You may also find other useful methods in the docs which I have linked to above. Let me know if this works for you.

You are using the `field` value for the second `param`. See the difference in how you did it compared to mine. Also, [See this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) as an example of the values to put in.

Comment: I was only using that date as an example of the layout, how would I use this with todays date?

Comment: I understand that but that was the best I could do with what I see of your code. That's what the `Calendar.getInstance()` returns. Then you add to that whatever attributes you need if you need to set a different date

Comment: can't seem to get this to work, error lines are showing up under the objects in the parameters above. I'll add some more code

Comment: We are making progress but what are the errors? Did you import the Calendar? Also, you may need to change it to, Calendar.MONTH and so on. Try that. Hope this helps

Comment: seems to think its saturday the 2 march, this is what I have written

Comment: sorry keep pressing return thinking it'll start a new line'code'Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
       now.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
       now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);'code'

Comment: dunno how to add code to this bit i'll add it at the bottom above

Comment: also have this to format - whatDay.setText(DateFormat.format("E, dd MMMM", now));

Comment: Yeah, comments aren't really made for code. It's best to edit the question as you have now. The second `param` in each `set` method should be one of the constants or variables that it shows in the docs for each attribute which I have a link to in my answer

Comment: I checked the Calendar Docs there but doesn't seem to show an alternative value from what we have put in

Comment: sorry mate have to uncheck it, they wont let me ask anymore questions so need to expand this one

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Just a little tip. I haven't went through all of your questions but your privileges were probably suspended due to the amount of downvotes. One thing to help that is to work on better questions...I could try and look at them sometime if you want. Also, you have a lot of unaccepted questions with answers that contain several upvotes. Accepting answers that have helped and building up rep by answering questions efficiently will help. Good luck to you

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate that. Yeah I guess my questions are a bit rushed, when deadlines are tight and your head is jumbled up in code it can be hard to find patience to write a good question. Guess I learned my lesson the hard way haha

Comment: No problem, I hope they let you ask questions again soon. Just remember that the community is here to help so everyone likes good, thought out and clear questions that show effort