# How to return all date of week

Tags: java, android

I want return today's date and plus the next 7 days.  How could I manage this?

I mean if today's date is 31.07.2013 Wednesday I want it returns also 1.08.2013 Thursday and so on...

Comment: You could just increment a date by one day 7 times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(today.getTime());
    today.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    System.out.println(today.getTime());
    today.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    System.out.println(today.getTime());
```

Comment: @downvoter, please care to leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String date = (new Date()).toString();  // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);  // number of days to add
date = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

I haven't tested it :)

Comment: This is wrong, this will give the day after 7 days from today

Answer (score 0):

```
here is the code:

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Date date = new Date();
            String todaydate = dateFormat.format(date);

            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
            Date nextDate= cal1.getTime();

            String weekAfter = dateFormat.format(nextDate);

            System.out.println("todaydate  " + todaydate);
            System.out.println("weekAfter  " + weekAfter);
```

Output:

todaydate  2013-07-31
weekAfter  2013-08-06

Comment: Read the question again

Comment: @ruchira provided the concept. not spoon feeding.