# Add one month to a date in Velocity template

Tags: java, date, velocity

I have a Velocity template with variable `$facet.name` holding a date. Now I want to add one month to this date. I'm doing it as following:

```
#set( $cal = $Calendar.getInstance.setTime($facet.name) )
$cal
$cal.add($Calendar.MONTH,1)
$cal.getTime.toString
```

Last 3 rows are evaluated as is: I got

```
$cal
$cal.add($Calendar.MONTH,1)
$cal.getTime.toString
```

as output.
How should I do it correct way?

Comment: Please, don't implement business logic in template! Do the calculation on the Java side, properly, and add it in the context. You'll thank yourself: it is very painful to debug code written into a template. Also, using a variable named as `$facet.name` to hold a date is something I'd get mad about.

Comment: I'm playing with Solr and its Velocity intergation. There is no business logic and `$facet.name` is the name provided to me from Solr

Comment: Where does $Calendar came from in your template? Are you using a vtl-tool for that?

Comment: it is a standard Java class. I also tried to use full name with packages

Comment: I know that this is a standard class. But why do you think you can use it in a velocity template? $Calendar is a *variable* named 'Calendar' and if you haven't set it then $Calendar is null.

Comment: How can use then this class? I found in the documentation, that I should add it to context, but can I do it from template?

Comment: Look at my answer. And regarding to @ppeterka: Can you modify the context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Comment: no, it is not. It is a question of executing java code from velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java [Calendar.setTime(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) returns **void**

This line

```
#set( $cal = $Calendar.getInstance.setTime($facet.name) )
```

would try to assign the "void value" returned by the setTime() method to $cal... (though I definitely think, there should be an error message about this somewhere)

Try:

```
#set( $cal = $Calendar.getInstance() )
$cal.setTime($facet.name)
```

**EDIT**

I think the $Calendar.getInstance is not valid without the parentheses. (Velocity doc says this: `A VTL Method Body consists of a VTL Identifier followed by an left parenthesis character ("("), followed by an optional parameter list, followed by right parenthesis character (")").`)

Also, take note: even `$Calendar` works only if you added the `Calendar.class` to the context as `"Calendar"`. You only have what you put into it (or what the tool puts ito it for you to use...)

**EDIT2**

Trouble is, it is *quite limited* what SOLR puts into the Velocity context:

**Velocity Context**

- **esc**: a Velocity [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/generic/EscapeTool.html) instance
- **date**: a Velocity [ComparisonDateTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ComparisonDateTool.html) instance
- **list**: a Velocity [ListTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ListTool.html) instance
- **math**: a Velocity [MathTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/generic/MathTool.html) instance
- **number**: a Velocity [NumberTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html) instance
- **page**: a [PageTool](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/contrib/velocity/src/main/java/org/apache/solr/request/PageTool.java?view=markup) instance. page only is added to the context when response is a QueryResponse.
- **request**: a [SolrQueryRequest](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/request/SolrQueryRequest.html)
- **response**: a [QueryResponse](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html) most of the time, but in some cases where QueryResponse doesn't like the request handlers output (AnalysisRequestHandler, for example, causes a ClassCastException parsing "response") the response will be a SolrResponseBase object.
- **sort**: a Velocity [SortTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html) instance

([from SOLR docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter))

For what you try to do , the [ComparisonDateTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ComparisonDateTool.html) seems to be appropriate...

Comment: no, it gives the same result. even simple code like this: `    #set( $next_month = $Integer.parseInt("3") + 1 )
    $next_month` is not evaluated correctly

Comment: @damluar I just noticed something (I have dealt with VTL a long time ago...), that as I recall, we used either $object.<fieldname> OR $object.<getterName>() so I think the $Calendar.getInstance is not valid. (Velocity doc says this: `A VTL Method Body consists of a VTL Identifier followed by an left parenthesis character ("("), followed by an optional parameter list, followed by right parenthesis character (")").`) But then the Integer.parseInt should work, if the context has the `Integer.class` properly included.

Comment: now the question is: how can I include class into context from within template?

Comment: @damluar I think you can't... Is there no possilibity to influence what SOLR puts into the context? (Just saw [this unnaswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026801/putting-parameters-or-variables-into-solr-velocity-context) so this does not seem to be trivial)

Comment: ok, thank you for the help. I tried Velocity cause it is provided from Solr out of the box. I will implement UI with JSF anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems from the comments you think you can use java code in velocity. That is not true. This is possible in jsp and e.g. php, but not in velocity templates (you know, this "don't use business logic in your view" thing).

If you need to call some logic then

- you have to add an instance to your velocity context that contains something that you can call a method on or
- you have to use a tool, e.g. the date tool from velocity generic tools. Info can be found here: http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/generic.html

Comment: You should read my edited answer, and the comments OP gave to my answer. No way to modify the context...

Comment: Then he should go the tools way. No need to modify the context with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the DateTool available, you can use it to add the milliseconds directly to your date object and avoid having to deal with the calendar object all together:

```
#set ($datePlusOne = $date.toDate($math.add($facet.name.time, 86400000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add 5 days to a date held in a variable. I tried few things and the following code works fine for me

```
#set($calendar = $date.getCalendar())   
$calendar.setTime($myDate)  
$calendar.add(6,5)  

$date.format('MM/dd/yyyy',$calendar.getTime())
```

I hope this will help you to add/subtract any number of days to a given date.