# How to Increase the date by one

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have date and time in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm` I want to increase the `dd` by one 
i.e `2013-10-24:11:20` to `2013-10-25:11:20`

```
    SimpleDateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm");
    time = mSDF.format(calSet.getTime());//calset in my calendar instance
```

I don't know what exactly my time/date is .I only know that I have to increase date by one for `time` variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java is exactly the same problem.

Comment: I think below link can guide you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use calendar

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setDate(yourdate); // pass parsed Date object
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.getTime(); // here you will get your date
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Calendar` `add` method.

```
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29) method :

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
```

Output :

```
2012-12-31:10:25
2013-01-01:10:25
```