# How to show only 7 days in a calender from current date to next 6 days

Tags: android

i'm developing android app which requires calender with Only 7 days from current date : if Today is Wed day, so results will be wed -- till tuesday i need to show in view of my calender.

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
widget.setSelectedDate(instance.getTime());
Calendar instance1 = Calendar.getInstance();
instance1.set(instance1.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
Calendar instance2 = Calendar.getInstance();
instance2.set(instance2.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.DECEMBER, 31);
widget.state().edit()
        .setMinimumDate(instance1.getTime())
        .setMaximumDate(instance2.getTime())
        .commit();
widget.addDecorators(
        new MySelectorDecorator(this),
        new HighlightWeekendsDecorator(),
        oneDayDecorator);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456793/get-next-7-days-starts-from-the-current-day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get next 7 days starts from the current day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456793/get-next-7-days-starts-from-the-current-day)

Comment: do you want to show dialog

Comment: Yes i want to show show calenderview with only 7days i need to select any one it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `CalendarView` or `DatePickerDialog`, you can set `min date = today` and set `max date = today + 7`.

```
CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.cl);
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long maxTime = currentTime + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
calendarView.setMinDate(currentTime);
calendarView.setMaxDate(maxTime);
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You leave your code exactly how it is and just remove your set call. When you call getInstance for a calendar you will get back a calendar instance that is set to the current date and time.

Ex:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

for(int i = 0; i < 7;i++){
    Calendar[i] = format.format(date.getTime());
    date.add(Calendar.DATE  , 1);
    System.out.println("date :" + Calendar[i]);
}
```