# Calendar DATE trouble

Tags: java, calendar

```
Date toDate = new Date(114, 5, 30);    
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendarTo = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(toDate);
            calendarTo.setTime(toDate);
            calendarTo.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

this is how I initialize calendars and I am trying to put NEXT day in calendarTo
but when I getting calendar.Date it is equal to calendarTo.DATE and is equal to 5.. why?
And how I could finally increment this DATE value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you if you are using Java 8 or newer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23910924/1115554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is the default value of DATE in Calendar class. Which is 5

```
public final static int DATE = 5;
```

But when I print the dates from your code, looks like it is fine.

```
Date toDate = new Date(114, 5, 30);    
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar calendarTo = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(toDate);
                calendarTo.setTime(toDate);
                calendarTo.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                System.out.println(toDate);//Mon Jun 30 00:00:00 IST 2014
                System.out.println(calendarTo.getTime());//Tue Jul 01 00:00:00 IST 2014
```