# Date "DAY" auto increment by 1

Tags: java

How can i make my date "DAY" only auto increment by 1 every time I get the date value. 
Example my current expire date is 20141031, after increment it will changed to 20141101.

```
SimpleDateFormat timestampFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
SimpleDateFormat timestampFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

String EXPDATE          = common.setNullToString((String) session.getAttribute("SES_EXPDATE"));  // 31- 10-2014

String tempEXPDATE = timestampFormat.format(timestampFormat2.parse(EXPDATE)); //20141031
int intExpdate = Integer.parseInt(tempEXPDATE.substring(6,8)); //30
```

Comment: Use [Calendar.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Use [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) or [threetenbp](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks guys, problemd solved :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will help you

```
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     Date date=timestampFormat.parse(tempEXPDATE);
     cal.setTime(date);
     cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     String newDate=timestampFormat.format(date);
```

Note that I have picked `timestampFormat` and `tempEXPDATE` from your code.

Comment: Awesome... it's working !! thousand of thanks to you !! 

but i changed the
    String newDate=timestampFormat.format(date);
to
    java.util.Date d1 = cal.getTime();
    EXPDATE = timestampFormat.format(d1);

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). You can use [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse("20141031"));
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1); // add one day to current date
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Out put:

```
20141101
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can use the new Date/Time API. 
With Java 8 you can simply use the `plusDays()` method:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(yourDateString, formatter);
LocalDateTime plusOneDay = dateTime.plusDays(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Java 7 with [threetenbp](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.threeten%7Cthreetenbp%7C1.0%7Cjar):

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

---

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd").format(
    LocalDate.parse(
        "31-10-2014",
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
    ).plusDays(1)
)
// 20141101
```