# how to add days to date in java using simpledateformat and store output in string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code which generates the output as **"9/2/2014"**

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws ParseException
{
    java.util.Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
    System.out.println(sd.format(d));


}
```

Now i need to add some n no of days and i wanted to get the output as 9/12/2014

please help me ...

Comment: you can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for date manipulations.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: @Raghuveer Is it so difficult to search for calendar example? There are tons of articles in the web. Please go and search for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you want add month, or days to your date, use something like that:

```
public static Date addDays(Date date, int days)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days); //minus number would decrement the days
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

to add month use `Calendar.Month`

Answer (score 0):

[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) has methods for date manipulations. First create Calendar instance and set date to it

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTime(new Date());
```

Then you can use `calendar` instance to add days like

```
 calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,10);
```

to get date from calendar, use

```
 System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```