# How to get next day and previous day of a given date?

Tags: java, datetime

How to get next day and previous day in Java when we know some date? For example, suppose `getBatchDate() = 2014-08-21`. How to get previous day and next day with lesser code?

Comment: Try using joda-time framework. It comes with handy methods.

Comment: Don't bother with joda-time for this.  As the two correct answers here demonstrate, this can be done without it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use calendar to add values:

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(getBatchDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date nextDay = cal.getTime();
    cal.setTime(getBatchDate());
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    Date prevDay = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Calendar#add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method where first argument is `DATE` and second value is either 1 or -1 based on next or previous day.

sample code:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);  // set the date
//cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // next day
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // prev day
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would include Joda DateTime in your pom 
You can make a DateTime object, which has methods add or minus a day, and its actually quite reliable.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Actually if you insist on using Joda-time, which in this case is entirely unnecessary, the correct class to use is `LocalDate`, not `DateTime`.  The correct method to use is `plusDays`, in the `LocalDate` class.  If you're going to recommend a tool, please at least recommend the correct use of the tool.