# Modify Date type (Java)

Tags: java, date, increment

need some help here with the Date type.

I'm managing a CreditCard class with the following parameters

```
public class CreditCard extends Card{
Date monthlyFee;
double amount2pay;
public CreditCard(StandardAccount yourAssociatedBankAccount,Date monthlyFeeDay) {
    super(yourAssociatedBankAccount);
    monthlyFee=monthlyFeeDay;
    cardType="Credit Card";
}
```

when the CreditCard is created, I have to set the MonthlyFeeDay (which is for instance "today + 30 days").

The following function has to create the CreditCard

```
   public void createCreditCard(StandardAccount anAccount){
    Date today= new Date();
    Card newCard= new CreditCard(anAccount,today);
    anAccount.addCard(newCard);
    cardsList.add(newCard);
}
```

The fact is, I don't know how to increment the variable "today" by 30 days. I don't know how to set the day of the next month.
Any hint?

Comment: What Java version is in use here?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Calendar for this.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
Date date =  c.getTime();
```