# how to get current date and 7thday from current day in android? and I want to show the dates in below format given by the image

Tags: android, date, android-calendar

In the given image first date is current date with month and day.
and another date is 7th day from current date.

[image]

I tried with the below code::

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd.MM.yyyy");

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                Log.i("dateTag", sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
            }
        tvDate1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.calender_view1);
        tvDate1.setText("" + DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", System.currentTimeMillis()));


tvDate2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.calender_view2);
        tvDate2.setText("here want to print 7thday");
```

Comment: Your code is highly inefficient. Instead of a loop which `adds 1 day 7 times`, you should `add 7 days in a single step`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd.MM.yyyy");
Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentdate=dateFormat.format(currentCal.getTime());
currentCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); 
String toDate=dateFormat.format(currentCal.getTime());
```

Comment: how can i calculate if i have another date ? @Nas

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ use currentCal.setTime(Date obj). Pass your Date obj after creating calendar instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need strings for each day, and then use a switch on the DAY_OF_WEEK.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Java Class

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateAndTimeArithmetic {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Java calendar in default timezone and default locale
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        System.out.println("current date: " + getDate(cal));


        //adding days into Date in Java
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        System.out.println("date after 2 days : " + getDate(cal));

        //subtracting days from Date in Java
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
        System.out.println("date before 2 days : " + getDate(cal));


       //adding moths into Date
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
        System.out.println("date after 5 months : " + getDate(cal));

        //subtracting months from Date
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -5);
        System.out.println("date before 5 months : " + getDate(cal));

        //adding year into Date
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
        System.out.println("date after 5 years : " + getDate(cal));

        //subtracting year from Date
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);
        System.out.println("date before 5 years : " + getDate(cal));

        //date after 200 days from now, takes care of how many days are in month
        //for years calendar takes care of leap year as well
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 200);
        System.out.println("date after 200 days from today : " + getDate(cal));

        System.out.println("current time in GMT: " + getTime(cal));

        //adding hours into Date
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
        System.out.println("Time after 3 hours : " + getTime(cal));

        //subtracting hours from Date time
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -3);
        System.out.println("Time before 3 hours : " + getTime(cal));

        //adding minutes into Date time
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 3);
        System.out.println("Time after 3 minutes : " + getTime(cal));

        //subtracting minutes from Date time
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -3);
        System.out.println("Time before 3 minuets : " + getTime(cal));

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return current Date from Calendar in dd/MM/yyyy format
     * adding 1 into month because Calendar month starts from zero
     */
    public static String getDate(Calendar cal){
        return "" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE) +"/" +
                (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return current Date from Calendar in HH:mm:SS format
     *
     * adding 1 into month because Calendar month starts from zero
     */
    public static String getTime(Calendar cal){
        return "" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +":" +
                (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }

}

Output:
current date: 23/7/2012
date after 2 days : 25/7/2012
date before 2 days : 23/7/2012
date after 5 months : 23/12/2012
date before 5 months : 23/7/2012
date after 5 years : 23/7/2017
date before 5 years : 23/7/2012
date after 200 days from today : 8/2/2013
current time in GMT: 6:12:53
Time after 3 hours : 9:12:53
Time before 3 hours : 6:12:53
Time after 3 minutes : 6:15:53
Time before 3 minuets : 3:15:53
```

And if Need Some More ways to solve your probelem check this stackoverflow post
[How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)