# how to add a single day to "dd/mm" format in java

Tags: java, date

I have a date in `dd/mm` `(15/07)` format, I need to add a single day to this date, so it becomes `16/07`.

How can I do this in the easiest way in java?

Comment: Is just a string or some date typed class?

Comment: it's a string and I need a string with increased date

Comment: You should convert it into a DateTime type, so that leap years etc. are dealt with, then back to string.

Comment: If you only have day and month, then you should know that the result may not be correct. For example: what should be correct result for `28/02`? Is it `29/02` or `01/03`? Or are the day and month always of "this" year?

Comment: @Tom is absolutely right, and that is also the reason why a class like `java.time.MonthDay` does not extend `Temporal` meaning does not offer any chance to add a day for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar.

```
String dt = "15-07-2016";  
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // number of days to add
dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The [Answer by Goel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392743/642706) is correct but outmoded.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `MonthDay`

The java.time classes include the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class to represent a month+day without year and without time zone.

```
String input = "15/07";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM" );
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse( input , formatter );
```

## Cannot increment February 28

As commented by Tom, you cannot reliably increment February 28. In most years you would get March 1 but in [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) you get February 29. This is why the `YearMonth` class lacks any `addDays` method.

So you need to (a) assume/supply a year, (b) refuse to increment the one day of February 28, or (c) arbitrarily increment to March 1 from February 28 to ignore any possible 29th.

Let's look at the first option, supplying a year.

To get the current year we need the current date. To get the current date, specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
int year = today.getYear();
```

We can apply that year number to change our `YearMonth` into a `LocalDate`. From there the `LocalDate::plusDays` method increments to the next day. From the resulting instance of `LocalDate` we extract a `YearMonth` object.

```
LocalDate ld = monthYear.atYear( year );
LocalDate nextDay = ld.plusDays( 1 );
YearMonth ymNextDay = MonthDay.from( nextDay );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public String addDay(String date) {
    String[] dateSplit = date.split("/");
    String day = "" + (Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]) + 1);
    return day + "/" + dateSplit[1];
}
```

But this isn't really a nice solution, because this doesn't handle month or year swaps (This you can add by yourself using the % operator)

Or you use the SimpleDateFormat like here: [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)