# modify existing date and result would be in same format with java

Tags: java, date

I have a Date which is coming like this Thu Dec 31 16:00:00 EST 1969.

So i just need to add one day in this so that i will get Thu Jan 01 16:00:00 EST 1970.

any idea with java ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Comment: yes i have tried with Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     System.out.println(calendar.getTime());// print today's date
     calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

Comment: #simon b i am not able to find any solution for my question

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: Is your question specific to 'Dec 31 16:00:00 EST 1969.' as it is before the clock starts in Java Date object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add a single day to "dd/mm" format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392706/how-to-add-a-single-day-to-dd-mm-format-in-java)

Comment: This input string is terrible. Educate the publisher of that data about UTC and about ISO 8601.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Java 8, you could use ZonedDateTime.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 EST 1969", dtf);
zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.plusDays(1);

System.out.println(dtf.format(zonedDateTime));
```

Comment: getting java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Thu Jan 01 16:00:00 EST 1970' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: @Er KK Chopra, I edited the post, now it should be ok.

Comment: **Incorrect.** `LocalDateTime` is precisely the *wrong* class to be using here. That class cannot be used to represent a moment. That class purposely ignores time zones. So your results will be incorrect when failing to account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Use `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque for your remark, I changed the solution.