# Java: how can i add a day on Date?

Tags: java, date

Working on Java 7, i have the following String date = "12/04/2012".

I converted the String to a Date format:

```
Date date_converted = DateUtils.parse(DateUtils.STANDARD, date);
```

Now i want to add a day to my Date, someone can help me?

Comment: What is your  java compiler version

Comment: Added version to question.

Comment: take look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Comment: Can you please mention import of Date

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setDate(date_converted);
cal.add(Calendar.Date, numberOfDays);
date_converted = cal.getTime();
```

The above is the easiest way of doing it in Java 7. You can easily subtract days by passing negative number.