# How to get the date from 7 days from now

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to get the date 7 days from what the current date is. I am not to sure what code would be needed.

The code I have to find the current date is:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Or better yet, start with the Oracle docs & tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code on stack overflow....
[How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime( dateFormat.parse( inputString ) );
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 7 );
```

Answer (score -2):

`LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(7)`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html