# math with dates , + - and ADD

Tags: java, android

Hello guys i have a tricky question for you that i really cant find a solution out there.

What i want to do is to have 3 date/time inputs on simpledateformat

```
Date 1 
Date 2
Date 3
```

and basicaly i want to get difference of months days hours and minutes from date 1 - date2 and result of those 2 dates to be added on the firth date

for example 11/3/2017 12:30 - 7/3/2017 = 4 days and ADD that to current date 13/3/2017 13:30 + 4 days and 1 hour = 17/3/2017 14:30

i know how to get the diference in days hours and minutes , i cant get the second part of adding the result to the current date

any ideas?

thank you in dvance

Comment: use `Calendar` instance

Comment: is this tricky ?? :)

Comment: **see this link** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Comment: mm for one week learner yes! @thanga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to add days and hours

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, yourDays); //adds days to your date
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourHours); //adds hours to your date
cal.getTime(); //to get Date instance
```

To decrement dates just add negative number, for example:

```
int yourDays = -daysVariable;
int yourHours = -hoursVariable; //
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, yourDays); //decrement days
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourHours); //decrement hours
cal.getTime(); //to get Date instance
```

Comment: I edited answer, just add negative number to your date do decrement date. If it is helpful please accept the answer and upvote ;) @Unlimited

Comment: i did but im very low on rep and my vote is recorded but not published :/

Answer (score 0):

Get a date object using the simpledate format

Because it is an object of the same type
Comparison is possible

Comment: the same principle goes with time?

Comment: 1.you make Date object  
 - String to Date

2. Date - Date

3. Date to String 

You can do this by converting different types of characters into date types

Comment: sorry my english is low level  TT

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use getTime and add days throught miliseconds.

For example, if you can get the difference of days you should use something like this

`date1.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000*4`

(where 4 is the difference you want to add)

You can use Calendar too.

Comment: ill try that because under some conditions i want to minus days or hours from the current date

Comment: If you have any trouble let me know

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your ultra fast replies!

I solved it by using Mij Solution

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(yourDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, yourDays); //adds days to your date
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, yourHours); //adds hours to your date
    cal.getTime(); //to get Date instance
```

To add days and

tis code to decrese days

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(yourDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -yourDays); //adds days to your date
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -yourHours); //adds hours to your date
    cal.getTime(); //to get Date instance
```

and to control if date is bigget than my current date i used this condition

```
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Date strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
     if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
     catalog_outdated = 1;
      }
```

it returns -1 if the date is past from current 
+1 if date is bigger that current or whatever
and 0 if dates are equal

again thank you!