# How to double the number of Days to given Date?

Tags: java

## Problem

Given a Date.Add specified number of days to endDate.

Below is the **doubleDate** function that I need to define.

```
public static Date doubleDate(Date endDate,int noOFDays){
}
```

Solution:

```
public static Date doubleDate(Date endDate,int noOFDays){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
    c.setTime(endDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE,noOFDays);
    return c.getTime();     
}
```

> Can anyone guide me which method should I use to double the given endDate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov edited my code to show the difference

Answer (score 0):

This is how to add days to a given date.

```
public static Date addDate(Date endDate, int noOFDays) {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(endDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, noOFDays);

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Edited the Code