# How to set multiple attributes for calender object at once?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

This is my existing code snippet:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);  
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);  
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

I just want to assign those attributes at once, something like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

I am not sure it is possible or not, because I am new to java. Please help me if there is other way around to achive this.

If possible, please give others solutions also. Objective is to set the given `cal` object to `00:00:00.000`A.M.

**Edit 1: I think this question was clear and understandable. Please consider upvoting as I couldn't ask anymore questions on stackoverflow.**

Comment: Just use SimpleDateFormat. You can find solutions on you question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java/428966#428966

Comment: @Aleksei Please don't. Use DateTimeFormatter

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use one or more class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), for example `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: The period in the middle of @cricket_007’s comment is quite important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Calendar class can be set by the current generation of java time classes:

```
// Current time classes:
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
// LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 18);
LocalDateTime morning = today.atStartOfDay();

// Old classes:
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(morning.toEpochSecond()));
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, avoid the use of the legacy `Calendar` class.  Do use the classes from the java.time package, e.g.:

```
LocalDateTime todayAtStartOfDay = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
```

But if `Calendar` must be used, then consider using `Calendar.Builder`, e.g,:

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar.Builder()
            .setTimeOfDay(0, 0, 0, 0)  // hour, minute, second, millis
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloaded `set` method in the `Calendar` class:

```
void java.util.Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
```

Unfortunately you have to set your milliseconds manually. And you also have to use date formatter. Here an example

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS aa");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

It returns `00:00:00.000 AM`

Comment: You are 100% right. But first thing is that we don't know what Java version he uses. I suppose it is <8 because of `Calendar` class. Second thing it is just a simple example. He can improve it in many ways.

Comment: Java 8+ still contains calendar class, but it's end of life anyway