# How to compare date in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to compare the current date with the day before and the day next date.

Here is how I get current date and upload to firestore:

```java
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("time", sqlDate);

db.collection("users").document(user.getUid()).update(map);
```

Firestore screenshot:

[image: Firestore screenshot]

To get date from firestore

```java
db.collection("users")
                .document(user.getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    assert document != null;
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Date userDate = document.getDate("time");                  
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Format of date `Sun Apr 26 17:59:05 GMT+05:00 2020`

I want to get the next date and the previous date. Something like below:

> Previous date: Sat Apr 25 17:59:05 GMT+05:00 2020
>
> Today date: Sun Apr 26 17:59:05 GMT+05:00 2020
>
> Next date: Mon Apr 27 17:59:05 GMT+05:00 2020

Any suggest me how to get previous and next date from firestore using current date(uploaded to firebase).

Comment: Once you convert the timestamp from Firestore to a Date object, there are many ways to add time to it. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/428918